# Opencart 2 - Custom shipping Methods

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I was wondering whrere the shipping methods are set up in Opencart 2 - not in the Admin-Panel, but on the server and database.
I would like to set up my own (stub-) shipping method without the use of Extensions - maybe by cloning and customizing an existing one, but I can't find their location (i.e. the files to edit/copy) on the server.

Comment: You should look at the documentation of Opencart 2 if any exists, and try to connect to its database (sql server) and explore the tables might be a good starting point.

Comment: http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/

Comment: @NeeL you are right except in the part that says ***try to connect to its database (sql server) and explore the tables***,  exploring +100 tables is useless since there is no documentation for how and why open cart constructs and manipulates them, I think that the best way to understand OC modules is to debug (line by line) any page that uses these modules (in this particular situation, checkout process is the one)

Comment: The names and fieldnames of the database tables themselves should be enough documentation as they are mostly obvious with names like `product` and `category_to_store`.  That being said, I doubt there is much to glean about shipping methods from the database tables as any extension data is serialized and probably irrelevant to making a custom method.  Why chime in with advice (@NeeL) when you know nothing about the topic?  It's unhelpful and actually hurtful to SO imo.

Comment: Also, for the record, OpenCart does not use SQL Server or offer support for it out of the box.  Perhaps you meant MySQL - but please note, they are two different things.

Comment: Well because I think it's a good advice. When you look to add something to an existing software doing a bit of reverse-enginering can't be harmful.

Comment: @billynoah when I said "sql server" I meant any sql server..

Comment: I understand you had good intentions but your suggestion to look at the database, if taken, would likely result in many fruitless hours of searching through tables and finding nothing at all which relates to the question.  So it's not helpful.  And I could write "Read the documentation *if it exists*" on any question on SO - is that really helping anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shipping-method consists of the following parts on your server:

admin/

- controller/shipping/xx.php
- language/english/shipping/xx.php
- view/template/shipping/xx.tpl

catalog/

- language/english/shipping/xx.php
- model/shipping/xx.php

Comment: Also don't forget `class ModelTotalShipping` @ `<OC_ROOT>/catalog/model/total/shipping.php`

Comment: `/catalog/model/total/shipping.php` is not part of the a shipping method.

Comment: @xtools - Glad to see you found the answer yourself.  Here is a great thread on the topic which may help you avoid some common pitfalls: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=142&t=30226